# Where to get live video streaming examples ( GStreamer )?

Tags: video, video-streaming, live, gstreamer

Where to get live video + audio streaming examples ( GStreamer )? So for example streaming from File or Web camera to some web address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp) contains a few samples on how to do RTP streaming with GStreamer.

It's not clear from your post if GStreamer is really a requirement, so just FYI: live streaming is easier with VLC.

Answer (score 3):

This comes from the man pages...

An MPEG-1 system stream can be streamed via RTP from one machine to another.

Use this command on the receiver
gst-launch rtprecv media_type=mpeg1_sys ! mpegdemux name=demuxer ! { queue ! mpeg2dec ! xvideosink } { demuxer. ! queue ! mad ! osssink }

This command would be run on the transmitter
gst-launch filesrc location=mpeg1system.mpeg ! mpegparse ! rtpsend ip=IPorHostname