# streaming camera captured video to another location

Tags: python, video, opencv, streaming, ffmpeg

I am using Kinect camera capture images and compress them to video and save the video into the disk(python opencv). How can I stream and display it at another location? Because the video is made at real-time and I also need to display and stream it in real time.

Answer (score 1):

[Gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) >= version 0.10:

> The threading ability of 0.10 is an absolute must for any high-fidelity real-time media streaming.

GStreamer has [bindings for python](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/python.html), and [this interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2551287/176769) will help you get started.

[This post](http://blog.abourget.net/2009/6/14/gstreamer-rtp-and-live-streaming/) shares some useful Python code as well.